# Can one use TeX.SE to "promote" ones package

Tags: discussion, questions, site-promotion, packages

I'm wondering if it allowed/ethical to "promote" ones package on TeX.SE? Evidently I'm talking about free and open-source packages so not with a (direct) financial benefit. The idea is that many programmers write nice (hacky) packages for some need, but fail to attract other users/programmers to use/contribute to these packages.

The idea could be to ask some question like: "*How can you do X effectively?*" And the answer: "*With package Y*" (and evidently with a short introduction to the features Y offers). Since answering is open, other programmers can come up with their own package and its features.

**Short question**: will this practice be supported, or should these questions be closed?

Comment: There is definitely a tone of "primarily opinion-based" when asking how to do something "in the best way" or "effectively".

Comment: Allowed: Yes... ethical..hm.... it's too much self-promotion to do this and as Werner stated: 'primarily opinion based'. Perhaps the TeX.SX blog is the better place for this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: the aim is not that much self-promotion, but reuse of effort, and collaboratively creating more qualitative packages.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I see that point -- but other's won't see it, perhaps

Comment: You could also see: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/self-promotion-of-an-own-code .

Comment: I think that “promoting” is used with certain connotation in this question that does not apply to the TeX world at all. I think there's no problem with “promoting” (rather “using ones package to answer a question”), nor is unethical.

Answer (score 22):

If you actually find questions that are related to your package content, then you can fire an answering frenzy by mentioning *you can also do this with `<insert package name>`* and so on. Then I don't see why it should be a problem since we have loads of package authors answering questions with their own poison of choice. And it is a very very good thing since you get the information directly from the source.

But if it is a pretty obscure subject, say counting the keystrokes that left/right hand presses for typing a document<sup>1</sup>, then you can ask one-two questions, which really means **please don't overdo it**, with really well prepared content including those obscure keywords such that others can find it via googling, and then answer yourself.

But you better prepare the questions a bit better as you can see there is a defensive mode for such best practice stuff even though the whole site is about best practice answers instructing *don't do this, don't use that, those are deprecated* etc.

<sub>1) I trust the nerdiverse that it must exist somewhere</sub>

Comment: An answering *frenzy* might not be a good idea, but i fully agree with the rest.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have seen so many frenzies for editing, voting, closing tagging. Unlike them, proper answering frenzy never hurt.

Comment: True that. lala

Answer (score 19):

Strange, mostly I use the site for the opposite use:

**Don't use longtable**

[Longtable vs. supertabular: Which is right for which job?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/longtable-vs-supertabular-which-is-right-for-which-job#comment115385_55083)

**Don't use xspace**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/1090

**Don't use tabularx**

[Alignment in tabularx environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192656/alignment-in-tabularx-environment#comment444837_192656)

[Column width table in tabularx environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176257/column-width-table-in-tabularx-environment#comment407922_176257)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145918/1090

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241411/1090

**Don't use xmltex**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42207/1090

[XML or other markup to LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113820/xml-or-other-markup-to-latex#comment251068_113820)

Comment: You make `longtable` the slowest internet trolling ever, laid over twenty something years.

Comment: I'm noticing a trend… :)